# How to use RaggedTensor with tf.data API

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I would like to use RaggedTensor with the tf.data API, but it seems that the tensor shape is not correctly evaluated.
Here's an example that converts the batches into RaggedTensor, and back into Tensor:

```
import tensorflow as tf

shapes = [None]
types = tf.string
defaults = "<pad>"


def generator_fn_ragged():
    yield (
        ["The", "brown", "fox", "jumps"],
        ["The", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"],
    )


def input_fn():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        generator_fn_ragged,
        output_shapes=shapes,
        output_types=tf.string,
    )
    dataset = dataset.padded_batch(2, shapes, defaults)

    def _ragged(*features):
        return [tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(x, padding="<pad>") for x in features]

    dataset = dataset.map(_ragged)

    def _unragged(*features):
        return [x.to_tensor(default_value="<pad>") for x in features]

    dataset = dataset.map(_unragged)

    return dataset

dataset = input_fn()
for el in dataset:
    print(el)
    break
```

This outputs:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_7608:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=string>,)
```

As the shape is unknown, I am unable to use this tensor in my model.

How can I make it so the shape of the tensor converted from the RaggedTensor evaluates correctly?

FYI, this is the shape of the tensor if not converting to Ragged and back again:

```
Tensor("IteratorGetNext_4:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=string)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you must use ragged tensors here? What exactly are you trying to achieve?